# How to trigger javascript from Rails Controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3, I want to trigger a javascript that displays a pop-up after the user clicks a link to join a group which determines if a user is eligible for joining (controller action determines if they are eligible).

I need to pass the id to the controller, receive the message from the controller, and then trigger the javascript using the message.

I can't get the javascript to trigger.  Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  I think it's in the link in the view.

controller action:

```
def join
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])

if ineligible
  @message = "Sorry, you can't join." 

elsif current_user
  if !@group.already_joined(current_user)
    @message = GroupUser.create(@group,current_user,nil,nil)
  else
    @message = "You're already registered for this group"
  end

else      
  @message = "If you're already a user, but not a member of this group, please login, and then click the join link again.  If you aren't a user yet, please join!"
end
end
```

javacript in header

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>    

<script>
  $(#message).msg('<% @message %>', {
  type : 'confirm'
  });  
</script>
```

view

```
<%= link_to 'Join',{:onclick => {:controller => 'groups', :action => 'join', :id => @group.id} }%>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your `#message` selector in quotes:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>    

<script>
  $('#message').msg('<% @message %>', {
  type : 'confirm'
  });  
</script>
```